# Linux "missing" error

Tags: linux, shell, unix, syntax-error, minecraft

i am trying to write a .sh but get an error:
this is a minecraftserver updater (just for your info)

code:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Deleting Old Files
if [ -e spigot1.jar]; then
  rm spigot1.jar

fi

# Renaming
if [ -e spigot.jar]; then
  echo Renaming File...
  mv spigot.jar spigot1.jar
  echo Done.
  echo
  else
  echo

fi

# Downloading
echo Downloading File...
wget http://ci.md-5.net/job/Spigot/lastBuild/artifact/Spigot-Server/target/spigot.jar
echo Done.

# Comparing Files
echo
echo Testing if the files are the same... 
if diff -a -w spigot.jar spigot1.jar >/dev/null ; then
  echo Done.
  echo
  echo -----------------------------------
  echo
  echo You already have the newest version!  
  echo
  echo -----------------------------------
else
  echo Done.
  echo
  echo -----------------------------------
  echo
  echo Updated to a newer version! 
  echo
  echo -----------------------------------

fi

if [ -e spigot1.jar]; then
  rm spigot1.jar

fi

sleep 10s
```

but it pops up an error message saying:

```
test.sh: 4: [: missing ]
test.sh: 12: [: missing ]
```

is there a way to fix this?
i can't go on until this is fixed!
thanks in advance
- derpasaurs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need space

```
if [ -e spigot1.jar ]; then
```

instead of

```
if [ -e spigot1.jar]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above is exactly what you had, the problem is the lack of space between the `spigot.jar` and the `]`.

In response to your above comment, what is your code at this point.  The script is running fine for me with the above change.